# Angular Cannot read property of undefined with @Input

Tags: angular, typescript

I have create a component used in my parent component:

```html
<app-event-menu-nav [event]="event"></app-event-menu-nav>
```

Here is the component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ScrollNavigationService} from "../../../shared/services/scroll-navigation/scroll-navigation.service";
import {AuthService} from "../../../shared/services/auth/auth.service";
import {EventModel} from "@event/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-menu-nav',
  templateUrl: './event-menu-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-menu-nav.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class EventMenuNavComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: EventModel;

  constructor(
    private scrollService: ScrollNavigationService,
    public authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  scrollTo(anchor: string, offset?: number) {
    this.scrollService.scrollToAnchor(anchor, { offset });
  }

  isOwner() {
    return this.authService.currentUserId === this.event.creator;
  }
}
```

and the html

```html
<nav class="secondary_nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a (click)="scrollTo('description', -80 )">
          <i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i> {{ 'event.menu.description' | translate }}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="!event.onlineEvent">
        <a (click)="scrollTo('location', -60)"></a>
          <i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{ 'event.menu.location' | translate }}
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="scrollTo('comments')">
          <i class="fal fa-comment"></i> {{ 'event.menu.comments' | translate }}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isOwner()" >
        <a [routerLink]="['/organization/event', event?.id]">
          <i class="fal fa-cog"></i> {{ 'event.menu.admin' | translate }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm having an issue when I tried to run the Karma test:

> Cannot read property 'onlineEvent' of undefined

I don't know why I'm having this issue. Do I have to add something on my `spec.ts`?

Comment: This works, but only fails in test?  Please share your test setup code, you may just need to specify the input value for the test like (`componentUnderTest.event = {...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `event` is `undefined`, the evaluation of `event.onlineEvent` fails here :

```html
<li *ngIf="!event.onlineEvent">
```

You can prevent the template from rendering until `event` is defined, for example by adding a `*ngIf` on the `ul` :

```js
<ul *ngIf="event">
  [...]
  <li *ngIf="!event.onlineEvent">
```

If the value is always defined and fails only in the unit test, it means that you should give a value in the context of the unit test. For example, like this :

```js
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.event = [...]
fixture.detectChanges();
```